# Find which wires are what in a sjt power cable

Tags: power, ac, cables

I'm trying to figure out what wires are live, neutral and ground in my computer power cable. I'm getting some weird readings from the wires.

```
A - B = 51v
A - C = 117v
B - C = 65v
```

I'v read a bunch of articles but can't figure out what is what.

Comment: Why are you checking the voltages instead of pulling the cable and checking continuity?

Comment: ah, so if it beeps that means its the same wire?

Comment: Do you have a split phase transformer in your house electrical installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some power supplies have line-to-ground and neutral-to-ground filter capacitors like this picture:

[image: filter capacitor]

So line-ground and ground-neutral have half of the line-neutral voltage.

I think this is happen in your situation.
So my guessing:

- Ground is B
- Neutral may be A or C
- Line may be A or C

Try using neon screwdriver test light or test pens.

Answer (score 0):

There's something very ugly with your electrical wiring. The center pin of the block connector which goes into the computer *has* to be the earth/ground wire - no exceptions.

You should measure a low voltage between the center line and one side (less than 10V probably) and nearly 115V to the other side (='line').

In you case A-B + B-C = A-C, which is fine, but the you really should not have such large voltages on *both* sides of ground.